# php page load delayed until all ajax calls on current page are done

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP page (index.php) which is doing some ajax calls to another PHP pages
(example: data1.php ) to fill some divs with content.
When I click on another menu item (companies.php), the loading of the (companies.php) page gets delayed until all ajax calls on the (index.php) page are done.

But I need to stop all ajax calls when clicking on another page instead of waiting.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you set `async: false` on the AJAX calls?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan they should be loaded async because the page needs to be loaded before all divs are loaded

Comment: That's correct, which is why I was wondering if you'd used `async: false`

Comment: I'm not using `async: false`

Comment: In which case it's likely that you're hitting the limit of maximum allowed connections to your server. I'd suggest following @JainamShah's answers and calling `abort()` on any in-progress requests when the page is un-loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an ajax request you could use a variable to store it:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    success: function(result){}
});
```

Then you can abort the request on event trigger onbeforeunload:

```
request.abort();
```

You could use an array keeping track of all pending ajax requests and abort them if necessary.

```
var request = [];
request.push($.ajax(...))

var _abortAllRequests = function () {
    $(request).each(function (i, xhr) { xhr.abort(); });
    request = [];
}

$(window).on("beforeunload", function () { 
    _abortAllRequests();
});
```

Comment: How can I know that I clicked on another php page?

Comment: Hook to the `onbeforeunload` event or the `click` event of the specific `a` elements

Comment: There are multiple ajax calls running, how to stop them all?

Comment: use array variable and abort it

Comment: You mean I should add every ajax call to an array?

Comment: Please explain how!

Comment: yes, you need to store every ajax request in array. and then loop array and abort one by one.

Comment: Could you add this to your answer?

Comment: you can store before send read this: https://gist.github.com/msankhala/3fa2844c1fbad1f4c0185a8e3ef09aed